# How can I get ALL IP addresses of a web site?

Tags: php, networking, curl, hosting, monitoring

Is there any way to get a given website  all IP addresses?

Can CURL do it ? Is it possible in PHP ?

Comment: Do you need all IP's from a remote site or your site?

Comment: What do you mean all IP addresses? All the visits it receives or all IP that are in text within that website?

Comment: Actually, am working on both cases, in case it's yours, and in case it is not !

Comment: I mean all ip addresses where this site is hosted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dns_get_record`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php), like this:

```
$all_records = dns_get_record('example.com');
$ips = array();
foreach ($all_records as $r) {
    if ($r['type'] == 'A') {
        $ips[] = $r['ip'];
    }
    if ($r['type'] == 'AAAA') {
        $ips[] = $r['ipv6'];
    }
}
var_export($ips);
```

[`gethostbynamel`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php) also provides a simplified interface if you're only interested in IPv4 addresses.

Note that due to the limited response size and geographical preferences, you may need to ask  this query multiple times from multiple locations to get all (or most) addresses of a well-frequented domain such as google.com.

Comment: thanks phihag , but am testing dns_get_record and it gives me only one ip address

Comment: @MEznati With what domain? There may only be one address assigned to that domain, or your nameserver may leave out other ones.

Comment: am testing on www.symfony.com

Comment: @MEznati phihag is correct if the result is only one IP then there just one. not a problem by the functions. Your edit to my answer was therefore rejected.

Comment: @hek2mgl AM realy SORRY, I didn't mean to edit your answer, I was willing to leave a comment but I messed it up :(

Comment: @MEznati ... and I have not rejected it, others done :) at SO team, there was a bug in the review form. Wasn't able to click a button :)

Comment: @MEznati `www.symphony.com` has indeed just one IPv4 and no IPv6 addresses assigned to it. In virtually all cases, a load balancer will have one public IP and then distribute the requests to multiple servers behind it. Aside from timing (and debugging data injected by the administrators), a load balancer is invisible.

Comment: @MEznati no, this will not get the IP addresses of the machines behind a load balancer, that will not be possible at all.

Comment: @MEznati There are several ways of Load Balancing. Google for example uses DNS based load balancing, that's why I took it for example

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work when LB is used => you'll have only one IP address

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function for this: [`gethostbynamel()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php)

The function performs a DNS query and returns the resulting IPs

Example:

```
var_dump(gethostbynamel('google.com'));
```

Output

```
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  string(14) "173.194.70.139"
  [1] =>
  string(14) "173.194.70.113"
  [2] =>
  string(14) "173.194.70.100"
  [3] =>
  string(14) "173.194.70.138"
  [4] =>
  string(14) "173.194.70.102"
  [5] =>
  string(14) "173.194.70.101"
}
```

---

@MEznati About load balancing:

There are several ways of Load Balancing. Google for example uses DNS based load balancing, that's why I took it for example. If a form of internal load balancing is being used - meaning that the load balancer has 1 external IP and redirects requests to internal servers - you'll not being able to get those internal (private) IPs (that's by design).